# Error accrued when list wwwroot static images

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello guys i am trying to fetch all wwwroot images in list but it's showing me error.

Here My Controller:

````
```[BindProperty]
        public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
            var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents(Path.Combine("MultiImage"));
            var objFiles = contents.OrderBy(m => m.LastModified);

            ImageList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in objFiles.ToList())
            {
                ImageList.Add(item.Name);
            }
            return View("ListImages");
            // return new JsonResult(objFiles);
        }```
````

here is my view file:

````
```<div class="row">
        <div class="col container">
            <div class="col-10">
                @foreach (var items in Model.ImageList)
                {
                    var iPhotoUrl = "/MultiImage/" + items;
                    <img class="float-left p-2" src="@iPhotoUrl" height="150" />

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: you can see here : tinyurl.com/y9xrra5x @juunas

Comment: You are preparing the ImageList and doing nothing with it. You should send it to view as a model or in a viewbag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
You use Mvc , so you can make a model to contain ImageList.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

HomeController.cs:

```
     public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
        public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }
        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment)
        {
            webHostEnvironment = _webHostEnvironment;
        }
     
        public IActionResult Index(FileManagerModel fileManagerModel)
        {
            var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(this.webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
            var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents(Path.Combine("Files","images"));
            var objFiles = contents.OrderBy(m => m.LastModified);

            ImageList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in objFiles.ToList())
            {
                ImageList.Add(item.Name);
            }
            fileManagerModel.ImageList = ImageList;
            return View(fileManagerModel);
        }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model FileManagerModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col container">
        <div class="col-10">
            @foreach (var items in Model.ImageList)
            {
                var iPhotoUrl = "/Files/images" + items;
                <img class="float-left p-2" src="@iPhotoUrl" height="150" />

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

FileManagerModel

```
 public class FileManagerModel
    { 
        public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Option 2：Use Viewbag

Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col container">
        <div class="col-10">
 
              @foreach (var items in ViewBag.ImageList)
            {
                var iPhotoUrl = "/Files/images" + items;
                <img class="float-left p-2" src="@iPhotoUrl" height="150" />

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(this.webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
            var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents(Path.Combine("Files","images"));
            var objFiles = contents.OrderBy(m => m.LastModified);

            ImageList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in objFiles.ToList())
            {
                ImageList.Add(item.Name);
            }
            ViewBag.ImageList=ImageList;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Razor Pages, you should not use `return View()`.
Instead your OnGet function becomes:

```
        public void OnGet()
        {
            var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(WebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath);
            var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents(Path.Combine("MultiImage"));
            var objFiles = contents.OrderBy(m => m.LastModified);

            ImageList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in objFiles.ToList())
            {
                ImageList.Add(item.Name);
            }
        }
```